# Cannot use object of type stdClass as an array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My controller code

```
function edtpost($id)
{
    $this->load->model('post');
    $data = $this->post->edt_post($id);

    $this->load->model('category');
    $data['catname'] = $this->category->retrivecat();

    $this->load->view('dashboard/edit_post',$data);
}
```

**my model code**

**model post**

```
public function edt_post($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('post', array('id' => $id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            return $row;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**category model**

```
public function retrivecat()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row->catname;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

in controller & this code `$data['catname'] = $this->category->retrivecat();`

I have one error:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your that line with following :-

```
$data->catname = $this->category->retrivecat();
```

Comment: is it helpful for you?